# Errors when trying to compile the driver for the rtl8192su wireless adapter

Tags: installation, 10.10, drivers

I have a wireless to usb adapter, and I'm having some trouble to install the drivers on Ubuntu.

First of all, the `readme` says to use the `make` command, and I already got errors:

```
$ make
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.35-22-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/wellington/Desktop/rtl8192su_linux_2.4_2.6.0003.0301.2010/HAL/rtl8192u/r8192U_core.o
/home/wellington/Desktop/rtl8192su_linux_2.4_2.6.0003.0301.2010/HAL/rtl8192u/r8192U_core.c: In function ‘rtl8192_usb_probe’:
/home/wellington/Desktop/rtl8192su_linux_2.4_2.6.0003.0301.2010/HAL/rtl8192u/r8192U_core.c:12325: error: ‘struct net_device’ has no member named ‘open’
/home/wellington/Desktop/rtl8192su_linux_2.4_2.6.0003.0301.2010/HAL/rtl8192u/r8192U_core.c:12326: error: ‘struct net_device’ has no member named ‘stop’
/home/wellington/Desktop/rtl8192su_linux_2.4_2.6.0003.0301.2010/HAL/rtl8192u/r8192U_core.c:12327: error: ‘struct net_device’ has no member named ‘tx_timeout’
/home/wellington/Desktop/rtl8192su_linux_2.4_2.6.0003.0301.2010/HAL/rtl8192u/r8192U_core.c:12328: error: ‘struct net_device’ has no member named ‘do_ioctl’
/home/wellington/Desktop/rtl8192su_linux_2.4_2.6.0003.0301.2010/HAL/rtl8192u/r8192U_core.c:12329: error: ‘struct net_device’ has no member named ‘set_multicast_list’
/home/wellington/Desktop/rtl8192su_linux_2.4_2.6.0003.0301.2010/HAL/rtl8192u/r8192U_core.c:12330: error: ‘struct net_device’ has no member named ‘set_mac_address’
/home/wellington/Desktop/rtl8192su_linux_2.4_2.6.0003.0301.2010/HAL/rtl8192u/r8192U_core.c:12331: error: ‘struct net_device’ has no member named ‘get_stats’
/home/wellington/Desktop/rtl8192su_linux_2.4_2.6.0003.0301.2010/HAL/rtl8192u/r8192U_core.c:12332: error: ‘struct net_device’ has no member named ‘hard_start_xmit’
make[2]: *** [/home/wellington/Desktop/rtl8192su_linux_2.4_2.6.0003.0301.2010/HAL/rtl8192u/r8192U_core.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/wellington/Desktop/rtl8192su_linux_2.4_2.6.0003.0301.2010/HAL/rtl8192u] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.35-22-generic'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

`/home/wellington/Desktop/rtl8192su_linux_2.4_2.6.0003.0301.2010/` is the path where I copied the drivers on my computer.

Any idea how to solve this? (I don't even know what the error is...)

**update: sudo lshw -class network**

```
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 03
       serial: 78:e3:b5:e7:5f:6e
       size: 10MB/s
       capacity: 1GB/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10MB/s
       resources: irq:42 ioport:d800(size=256) memory:fbeff000-fbefffff memory:faffc000-faffffff memory:fbec0000-fbedffff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: wlan0
       serial: 00:26:18:a1:ae:64
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes multicast=yes wireless=802.11b/g
```

**sudo lspci**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 18)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 18)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller (rev 06)
00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 06)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 06)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev 06)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev a6)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 06)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 03)
02:00.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): VIA Technologies, Inc. VT6315 Series Firewire Controller (rev 01)
```

**sudo lsusb**

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:0158 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB 2.0 multicard reader
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 045e:00f9 Microsoft Corp. Wireless Desktop Receiver 3.1
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0b05:1786 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key part of your lsusb results is this:

Bus 001 Device 003: ID **0b05:1786** ASUSTek Computer, Inc.

There is a comment in a bug report on launchpad [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/492034/comments/35) specifically for this model.

The key part of that comment (& command #37) is the following you need to copy and paste into a terminal:

```
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/37387612/rtl8192sfw.bin.gz
gunzip rtl8192sfw.bin.gz
sudo mkdir /lib/firmware/RTL8192SU
sudo mv rtl8192sfw.bin /lib/firmware/RTL8192SU/
```

At the bottom of that comment is the statement that this should work just fine in Natty.

Comment: Thanks! \o/ If you now I'll look for how to do on Fedora, if you have any hint =)

Comment: Assuming that it is the same kernel 2.6.35 then this solution should also work on Fedora.

Comment: Sadly it's not the same for Fedora. If you have any idea, please, comment [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16072/how-to-make-my-usb-wireless-work-on-fedora). Thanks!